# sizeToFit UIButton when programmatically added to UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uistackview

After much searching I have started to give up

I have an iOS app (swift) that asks the user a series of questions and answers. The questions and answer are downloaded from a JSON file. There will always be 1 question per page but a varied number of answers. So the answers are UIButtons added to a UIStackView which is created in the xib. Here's the slight problem.

If I create an answer with more than 1 line (i.e. It has a line break in it), it will create a new line in the UIButton.titleLabel and expand the UIButton to fit. However, if the answer is long and spans over more than 1 line the UIButton does not expand. I have line wrap enabled to the label wraps correctly, however the button doesn't seem to realise it's width constraint within the UIStackView and therefore assumes it can display 1 long line of text and creates it's height accordingly - even when I call the ever trusty sizeToFit()!!!

I assume there is a simple setting such as "contentWidth" I am missing.

P.S. I would prefer not to calculate the size and manually set the height of the button. I want it to work with rotation as well which of course resizes the width

Comment: `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` could solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @dasdom did not solve it however. More interestingly `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` was in fact completely ignored (even when being set just as a constant like 5.) Setting "Baseline Relative" on my StackView made `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` be noticed however didn't do anything for changing my height. 
Will continue searching for answers!

Comment: Any fresh insight on this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I never found a fix for making the Button resize to it's own UILabel size correctly, it seems it constantly sees the text being able to fit to one line and work.

I did *overcome* the problem by replacing my UIButton with a UILabel. The UILabel then has `addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer())` and of course `userInteractionEnabled = true`

It's not the way I would like it to be but will keep my client happy until the next update to UIStackView!